# how to select radio button depends on condition in jsp with struts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, radio-button

i have jsp page with following code snippest...and it will show two radio buttons like car and bike

```
<bean:message key="label.vehicleType"/>&nbsp; : <html:radio value="Bike" property="vehicleType" idname="vehicleType" name="vehicleType">Bike</html:radio>
                                          <html:radio value="Car" property="vehicleType" idname="vehicleType" name="vehicleType">Car</html:radio><br/>
```

**If I select a radio button named as a car then it should show another two radio button like civic and BMW. or etc.**

How can I achieve this with `<logic:equal>` tag of struts tab library.

I am new with struts tag library and javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`<logic:equal>` will be of no avail here. You need JavaScript for that. Go like this,

1. Set grid/div having sub-radios to invisible
2. Define a function to show the grid/div having sub-radios
3. Upon selection of radios, invoke the function you defined

**Hints:**

1. `radio`'s `onchange` event can be used here.
2. In that function you need to validate some values before performing some real action.
3. You might need to hide the one and show the other one in case the selected radio is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using struts 2.x

you can use

```
<s:if test="some condition">
   your required code
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Everytime you use a JSP tag (Struts Tag extends JSPTag), the tags reads data from the servlet request  or session. If you want to use the `<logic:equal>` tag, you will have to send your radio selection to your Struts Action, retrieve a list of data to populate, and retrn back to your forward and display the data.

If not, use Javascript. You will have to check if the property of your form is checked and enable a `div` that contains the list of cars that you so wish. This means that you will have to load all your relevant data beforehand and hide your `div` on `onload()`.

Hope this helps.